# VB.Net: call sub from shared sub

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

I have some Ajax on a web page that feeds some data to a server-side VB.Net method.  Once that data is in the server-side method, I need to call another server-side method to use the data I just collected.  Here is a really simplified example:

```
' This method gets the input from the Ajax code on the web page.
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod> _
Public Shared Sub GetAwesome(VBInputText As String)
    Dim strTest As String = VBInputText
    ' Now that we have collected input from the user, 
    ' we need to run a method that does a ton of other stuff.
    DisplayAwesome(VBInputText)
End Sub

Protected Sub DisplayAwesome(AwesomeIn As String)
    ' The real app does a lot more than this.  For this example, it 
    ' just sets the text of a literal.
    litAwesomeResult.Text = AwesomeIn
End Sub
```

Of course, in the above example `DisplayAwesome(VBInputText)` gives me the 'Cannot refer to an instance member...' error.  So, is it possible now to call `Protected Sub DisplayAwesome` from `Public Shared Sub GetAwesome`?  I'm hoping to stay close to this sort of solution because it would play very well with the app as it is already written by another coworker.

Comment: Removed Shared from declaration of `GetAwesome()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately you cannot do this, Since the page method `DisplayAwesome` is defined as `Protected` and you requires an instance  of the class to access the `Protected` method. But changes in another instance will not reflect in the current UI. another thing you can do is Make `DisplayAwesome` as Shared, but this time you cannot access the UI elements inside the shared function.

The thing you can do in this situation is, return data to the called method(in front end) and handle the `litAwesomeResult.Text` there

Comment: Oh yeah, I was trying to avoid that.  Basically, there's a huge method called `doSave()` that needs to run after getting the Ajax input.  So, I need to write a value to the page and then run the big `doSave()`.

Comment: "Since the page method DisplayAwesome is defined as Protected" should be "Since the page method DisplayAwesome is not defined as Shared so you are required an instance..."

Comment: So, my solution will be a little bit of what I did not want to do, but it requires the least amount of rewriting.  We put a hidden button on the page (ugh) with the `doSave()` method connected to it.  When the Ajax function receives success, we use JavaScript to click the button that calls `doSave()`.  I don't like it, but it works.

Comment: I think I'll probably accept this as the answer.  It wasn't the answer I wanted, but the truth is important.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Call sub with name of Form Class like this:

```
FormName.DisplayAwesome(VBInputText)
```

In VB.Net, you can call the method not shared from a shared method with Name of Form Class by default instance, because The default instance is an object Form type that the VB application framework create and manage it, when the form is added to the project.

For more info see this :

[VB.NET Default Form Instances](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html)

Comment: You cannot do like this since it is not a `shared`  method, you need to create  an instance to access the method

Comment: You can do that from a another shared method! You can Test it !

Comment: could you please explain how it can be achieved?

Comment: If I try this, I can reference the DisplayAwesome sub, but then the litAwesomeResult referenced is that sub is null.

Comment: @un-lucky you can test it in dev !

Comment: I took the code of the question as an example : `Public Class Form1
    Public Shared Sub GetAwesome(VBInputText As String)
        Dim strTest As String = VBInputText
        Form1.DisplayAwesome(VBInputText)
    End Sub

    Sub DisplayAwesome(AwesomeIn As String)
        litAwesomeResult.Text = AwesomeIn
    End Sub
End Class`

Comment: The person who down vote, may give reason (explanation)?

Comment: I'll give that a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey, if I follow that example, form1 gives me the "cannot refer..." error.  If I instantiate a new Form1, I can get to DisplayAwesome, but then the literal in DisplayAwesome gives the "requires a reference" error.  I can refer to the literal if I instantiate a new _Default class, but then the literal can't be found (is null).